# JavaScript find an element like jQuery's .find()

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div></div>
   <p>
      <img src="#" widht="500">
   </p>
</div>
```

What I need is to get the value of `img` width attribute, but with plain JavaScript.

My js:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var width = document.querySelector('.parent > p > img').getAttribute('width');
        var img = document.querySelector('.parent > p > img');
        img.style.width = width+'px';
    };
```

But still I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

So, the `img` is not found I guess.. How can I find the `img` from `.parent` `div`?

Comment: In your html `width` is spelled wrong

Comment: The code should work fine, just tested it with the typo fixed.

Comment: Ok then how does it come I receive that error? And not work for me?

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '.getAttribute()' of null

That mean `document.querySelector('.parent > p > img')` return null, i'm not sure why since you're calling the script inside the `window.onload`, so if you've the same HTML/JS posted in the OP, just fix the typo `width` in you HTML code so :

```
<img src="#" widht="500">
_____________^^^^^
```

Should be :

```
<img src="#" width="500">
```

Then you're code should work as you could see in the example below.
Hope this helps.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var width = document.querySelector('.parent > p > img').getAttribute('width');
  var img = document.querySelector('.parent > p > img');
  img.style.width = width+'px';

  console.log(width);
  console.log(img.style.width);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div></div>
   <p>
      <img src="#" width="500">
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually spelled wrong on this example... And also the error I get is like the img is not found...

Comment: You could check my updated answer and notice that the script get the `width`.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to fix the typo with the `img` attribute `width` and can access it directly with `img.width`:

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.parent > p > img');
console.log('Width:', img.width);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div></div>
   <p>
      <img 
          src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/f380ecc42410414693b467ac7a97901b.png" 
          width="500">
   </p>
</div>
```